# BCP command adding new line character for the data having xml characters(<,>,\) while exporting data to CSV in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This is the BCP command I am using to export the data into CSV file in SQL server 2008:

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "exec ESB_ADT_DB.dbo.ProcTest" queryout "D:\outputfile.csv" -q -T -w -t,'
```

The problem is in table one column contains xml character (<,>,) for this data it's adding new line characters after writing to the file. How can I stop the bcp command to add new line characters to the data written into the file.

Thanks in advance for Help.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be doing this with a proc that outputs the  stream, so I just added a -r \0 to the end of the dynamic sql that invokes the BCP command. (I added the -a option too, but not sure if it affected anything. Also, code was originally written with the -c option too).

The command string now does this:

set @sql='bcp "exec my_xml_proc" QUERYOUT "outputfile.xml" -S server -U user -P password -c -a 65535 -r \0";

exec @sql;

The -r \0 seemed to work. I noticed changing the row-terminator produced one stream with the specified character at the end of the closing document tag when I specified a regular character (-r #), but the end-use needs a well-formed XML doc, so I changed to -r \0.